# Как сделать инструкцию, которая появляется при первом запуске

Tags: android

Где можно скачать пример кода под Android для справки (инструкции), которая появляется при первом запуске приложения и выглядит как несколько картинок, которые можно листать?

Comment: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Sample-Android-Apps

Comment: `ViewPager` как контейнер для пролистывания экранов и `TabLayout`для кружочков

Comment: А со своими библиотеками задолбали уже. Больше канители ради какой то фигни простецкой. Больше разбираться в них, чем самому написать. Или совсем уж обленились?

Comment: Что делать, когда [кто то ответил](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вам в первую очередь нужно создать класс, который будет возвращать в главное activity значение true если приложение запускается в первый раз, и false если не в первый соответственно,

```
public class PrefManager {
SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
Context _context;

int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

private static final String PREF_NAME = "androidhive-welcome";

private static final String IS_FIRST_TIME_LAUNCH = "IsFirstTimeLaunch";

public PrefManager(Context context) {
    this._context = context;
    pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
}

public void setFirstTimeLaunch(boolean isFirstTime) {
    editor.putBoolean(IS_FIRST_TIME_LAUNCH, isFirstTime);
    editor.commit();
}

public boolean isFirstTimeLaunch() {
    return pref.getBoolean(IS_FIRST_TIME_LAUNCH, true);
}
```

Где `isFirstTimeLaunch ()` возвращает `true`, если приложение запускается в первый раз.

Далее вам нужно создать класс например `WelcomeClass` в котором вы реализуете `ViewPager` и нужное вам количество макетов для прокрутки, с этого класса должно запускаться ваше приложение, в первую очередь в методе `onCreate()` класса `WelcomeClass` вы должны получить значение от класса `PrefManager` по `SharedPreference`,

```
prefManager = new PrefManager(this);
    if (!prefManager.isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
        launchHomeScreen();
        finish();
    }
```

который, если вернет значение `false` - приложение запускается не в первый раз, то должен произойти `Intent`который сразу откроет `MainActivity`, а если `true` - приложение запускается в первый раз, то класс прорисует макеты которые вы реализовали в нем.

```
private void launchHomeScreen() {
    prefManager.setFirstTimeLaunch(false);
    startActivity(new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```

Для получения более подробной информации можете пройти по [этой](http://www.example.com/) ссылке.

Comment: Ссылка с подробной информацией уже неактивна.