# Отловить первый запуск приложения

Tags: java, android

Объясните пожалуйста в теории, как отловить первый запуск приложения? 
Читал [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/600403/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5),
не то, все слишком громоздко.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В том вопросе просто кладут переменную `IsFirstTimeLaunch` в `SharedPreferences`, сразу после запуска приложения. Потом перед каждым запуском приложения проверяют её, если она проинициализирована и равна `true`, то приложение уже запускалось на данном устройстве.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, если кому интересно, то я сделал так:

Инициализировал статический `String`, и переменную типа `boolean`;

```
private static final String firstStartApp = "first_start";
private boolean firstStart;
```

В методе `onCreate` переменной `firstStart` задаю `true`;

```
firstStart = true;
```

В методе `onDestroy` переменной `firstStart` задаю `false` и сохраняю в `SharedPreferences`;

```
firstStart = false;
mEditor.putBoolean(firstStartApp, firstStart);
mEditor.apply();
```

Так как изначально было передано значение `true`, а потом `false`, `SharedPreferences` сохраняет последнее значение, и в самом начале, в методе `onStart`, я сделал простую проверку состояния переменной `firstStart` по `SharedPreferences`, и так как его последнее значение было `false`, то `true` второй и последующие разы уже не будет срабатывать;

```
boolean isCheck = mPreferences.getBoolean(firstStartApp, firstStart);
```

Ну и здесь собственно можно сделать условие:

```
if (isCheck) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Первый запуск", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Уже было запущено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: все [еще проще](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/446593/177345)

Comment: Это самое то, что мне было нужно. В своих попытках писать приложения, я всегда стараюсь сделать, чтобы было минимум кода, является ли это хорошим тоном?

Comment: даже по ссылке, так не используют билдер классы по codeStyle, особенно если транзакция асинхронная и тем более 1

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei Если вы про "method chaining" и мне, то я не считаю это принципиальным, хотя выглядит конечно "красивее"

Comment: да не, chain ну или strem, если брать Java8 ) просто в дройде мы редко используем, как правило. В Java конвенции есть рекомендация, делать это space ом на след строку через доту(точку). Но у вас даже другая проблема, вы постоянно используете класс editor, при этом именование однобуквенное. Я понимаю, что пример, и можно забить, но можно действительно немного правильней написать. Если билдер например Нотификашки, это бы сразу бросалось в глаза.